# Magento 2 Optimization Eliminate render-blocking resources on a Merged css and js files

Tags: magento2.2.6, optimization, render-blocking

I am optimizing the Magento 2.2.6 Website.In Google Page Speed test suggestion Eliminate render-blocking resources.

There are following files

> /pub/static/version1555309524/_cache/merged/be8f15a428b74dc06417a25ea03882ab.min.css
>
> /pub/static/version1555309524/frontend/namespace/theme/en_US/css/styles-l.min.css
>
> /pub/static/version1555309524/_cache/merged/70a3e0be566bb1f71f67c46f51c014fe.min.js
>
> /pub/media/styles.css
>
> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/1.4.0/css/perfect-scrollbar.css

How to do that ?

Thanks is Advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something not possible if it is magento default css.

Check with luma theme how many request calling.

Also some time merge size is big amount, then time no merge will be best solution.

Comment: Yes , I found many places but i can't get it